# How to add remove (toggle) class in angular when clicked

Tags: angular

I want to add active and open classes to the li when clicked and remove those classes if clicked again

```
 <li id="xx" class="treeview" (click)="menuToggle($event)">
 <li>
```

ts

```
 menuToggle(event: any) {
  this.renderer.addClass()
}
```

Comment: you can use NgClass https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: `event.target.classList.toggle('active')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use template reference variable to toggle classes in template:

```
<li #myLi class="treeview" (click)="myLi.classList.toggle('my-class')"><li>
```

---

Or if you want to do it in the component file (maybe if you want to add more logic):

component.ts

```
toggleClass = (event) => {
    event.target.classList.toggle('my-class');
}
```

template.html

```
<li class="treeview" (click)="toggleClass($event)"><li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

**HTML**

```
<li id="xx" [ngClass]="classFlag === true ? 'treeview' : '' " (click)="menuToggle($event)">
<li>
```

**TS**

```
 classFlag: boolean = false;
 menuToggle(event: any) {
    this.classFlag = !this.classFlag ;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these, No need to write specific function for it

```
<li [ngClass]="classFlag ? 'treeview' : '' " (click)="classFlag ? classFlag = false : classFlag = true">test</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using plain old Javascript:

```
// Find current active item
var myElement = document.getElementsByClassName('active');

// If found, remove the css class 'active'
if(myElement[0])
  myElement[0].classList.remove("active");

// Get the new active item
var currentElement = document.getElementById('message_' + messageId);
// Set the css class 'active'
currentElement.classList.add("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <li id="xx" class="treeview" (click)="menuToggle($event)">
 <li>
```

Component:

```
menuToggle(event:any) {
  event.target.classList.add('class3'); // To ADD
  event.target.classList.remove('class1'); // To Remove
  event.target.classList.contains('class2'); // To check
  event.target.classList.toggle('class4'); // To toggle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give an "active" property , something like this:

```
items = [
  {name:'a', active:false},
  {name:'b', active:false}
];
```

And inside the template:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="menuToggle(item)" [ngClass]="{'active': item.active}">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

And finally the menuToggle() method just toggles the active state of the clicked item:

```
menuToggle(){
 item.active = !item.active;
}
```