# How can I write following code in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
function toggleActive() {
  let option = document.querySelectorAll("li.option");
  for (let i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
    option[i].onclick = function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
        if (option[i].classList.contains("active")) {
          option[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
      }
      option[i].classList.add("active");
    };
  }
}
```

I want to write above code in Angular . In Angular How I write onclick function ?

Comment: For this code convert into angular please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351593/8213994) link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add remove (toggle) class in angular when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55351521/how-to-add-remove-toggle-class-in-angular-when-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

Writing an onClick handler in Angular is a simple matter of making an event-binding in your template, eg.: `(click)="doSomething"`.

Eventbindings is however one of the core concepts in angular, which is why I think you need to start from the very beginning.

However, you'd probably look into Angular's `FormsModule` or `ReactiveFormsModule` if you're working with forms (which Radio buttons usually are a part of)

Start out by taking the "Tour of heroes"-tutorials: https://angular.io/tutorial

...or binge some Udemy videos (etc.).

Comment: I have 4 li tags . If user has click any one of li tag  I want to show that li active class and remove if already active class on another li

Comment: I would look into the link that Aman supplied as a comment to your original question. I believe that you lack basic skills in regards to Angular, and should start by following a tutorials / video course - respectfully.